# Operator precedence for logical AND (&& )and logical OR (||)

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

As per the [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) for JavaScript, I can see that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

So, for the following code snippet:

```
let x, y;
let z = 5 || (x = false) && (y = true);
console.log(z);  // 5
console.log(x);  // undefined 
console.log(y);  // undefined
```

I thought that `&&` should be evaluated first and after short-circuiting for the `&&` part, `x` would be assigned the value `false`. And then only, `||` would be tried to be evaluated.

But, from the output of the `console.log`, I can clearly see that's not the case here.

Can someone please help me what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer, but surrounding with brackets `()` will clear up any ambiguity

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here, the output is correct. `z` is set to `5`, and since `5` is defined, the execution stops, there's no need to evaluate the other side of the `||`

Comment: Adding additional `()` still gives the same answer: `let z = 5 || ((x = false) && (y = true));`

Comment: Yes, it would (I meant in general). Here, it looks like your mixing up assignment and comparison operators.

Comment: Yes, why are we evaluating `||` in the first place, As the priority of `&&` is higher it should have been evaluated first. I was expecting z = 5, and  x = false, y = undefined

Comment: You might be interested in [Precedence And Associativity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#precedence_and_associativity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the operator precedence of `&&` of `||` means is that this:

```
let z = 5 || (x = false) && (y = true);
```

gets evaluated as:

```
let z = 5 || ((x = false) && (y = true));
```

and not as

```
let z = (5 || (x = false)) && (y = true);
```

It's not something that indicates *when* the values on each side of an operator is evaluated. That's done by the mechanics of each individual operator. For example, for `||`, it's [specified here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-binary-logical-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

```
1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LogicalANDExpression.
2. Let lval be ? GetValue(lref).
3. Let lbool be ToBoolean(lval).
4. If lbool is false, return lval.
5. Let rref be the result of evaluating BitwiseORExpression.
6. Return ? GetValue(rref).
```

It evaluates `GetValue(lref)` before `GetValue(rref)` runs.

In other words, operator precedence indicates which tokens are applied to which operator, and in what order, but not how/when a given operator evaluates the values on its left and right side.

Comment: I'm confused! Are you saying the evaluation for expression starts taking place from left to right and since the first operator encountered is || the mechanics for that is applied right or is it something?

Comment: First, operator precedence and associativity determine the grouping of each operator with respect to tokens. You could look at this as resolving a big complicated expression into segments of  `((expr1) OP (expr2))`. Only after that (after operator precedence is no longer under consideration, with everything already definitively grouped) does evaluation start, outermost first. For your code, that's `5 || expr2` where `expr2` assigns to the other variables. 5 is truthy, so expr2 is not evaluated.

Comment: Ok got this! Although, Based on the operator precedence and associativity it should be && instead of || but Apparently, The && and || operators use short-circuit logic, which means whether they will execute their second operand is dependent on the first.

Comment: @CertainPerformance what about `"foo" || alert("bar") && "baz"`? Even that `&&` has a higher precedence, alert function isn't invoked at all, because the short-circuiting happens on `"foo"`. Can you give an example when `&&` has a clear precedence over `||`?