# Why 10 == 10 || 10 != 10 && 10 < 10 is true

Tags: algorithm, operator-keyword

Why do the following operators work like this?

```
10 == 10 || 10 != 10 && 10 < 10 -> true
```

but why? Isn't the priority as shown below and doesn't it start from the left side?

```
         true       &&      false ?
(10 == 10 || 10 != 10) && (10 < 10)
```

I expected it to be false but it was true!

*Update: This is the same for all languages

Comment: it is not the same for all languages, but for most it will be calculated as `(10 == 10) || ((10 != 10) && (10 < 10))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operator precedence for logical AND (&& )and logical OR (||)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71983830/operator-precedence-for-logical-and-and-logical-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[&& has higher precedence than ||](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), at least for c++. Note that not all languages have the same operator precedence rules.

So, your expression is evaluated as `10 == 10 || (10 != 10 && 10 < 10)`, which is `true`